# Array returning Fixnum instead of String

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays similar to:

`[["Rosalind_0498", "AAATAAA"], ["Rosalind_2391", "AAATTTT"]]`

I I want to get the letter of the first array's second element I would expect to use `array[0][1][-1]`

This instead of returning 'A' returns 65, it's probably something simple to do with ruby arrays but I'm not sure why it is happening, can someone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

Is there a better way to do it then `array[0][1][-1..-1]`?

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to Ruby 1.9, accessing a string char with `[]` would get you the ascii value of this char.

Just use this in ruby 1.8:

```
array[0][1][-1].chr
```

Comment: Thanks I knew there had to be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

what version of ruby are you using?

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > a = [["Rosalind_0498", "AAATAAA"], ["Rosalind_2391", "AAATTTT"]]
 => [["Rosalind_0498", "AAATAAA"], ["Rosalind_2391", "AAATTTT"]]
2.0.0p0 :002 > a[0][1][0]
 => "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
p [["Rosalind_0498", "AAATAAA"], ["Rosalind_2391", "AAATTTT"]].flatten[1].chr #=> "A"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that when I try this I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method chr' for "AAATAAA":String`

Comment: which version of ruby you are using. I am using Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: But I'm probably going to use Anthony Alberto's solution.  If you look up in the comments I am using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @JoshD See [`here 1.8.7`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html) not supported `chr` method.

Comment: That is weird since the .chr method works for me but I have: `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]` maybe it's the patch level or something.